# Android - Animation start offset not working properly

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to make an animation that will slide from it's current position to the center of the screen and then flip. I have each moving component working properly but once I put them all into a set with the startoffset, the animation doesnt start until that offset ends and it performs all the animations at once. Any help on this is much appreciated.

**slide_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Slide down -->
    <translate 
        android:fromYDelta="0%" 
        android:toYDelta="100%"
        android:duration="1000"/>

    <!-- Set alpha to fully opaque -->
    <alpha 
        android:fromAlpha="0.8"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="1000" />

    <!-- Flip image once it's in the center -->
    <!-- ***** HERE IS THE only offset I set ****** -->
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:duration="200" />
</set>
```

**calling code**

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), slideDirection);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {             
            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {                
            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mCallBack.categorySelected(view.getId());
            }
        });

        view.clearAnimation();
        view.startAnimation(anim);
```

Thanks,
Dman

Answer (score 2):

Animation offsets always calculate from the start of the animation. If you want your animations to play one by one, then you have to calculate the offsets yourself.

The following will play the translate for 1 second, then alpha for another second followed by scale for 200ms -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Slide down -->
    <translate 
        android:fromYDelta="0%" 
        android:toYDelta="100%"
        android:duration="1000"/>

    <!-- Set alpha to fully opaque -->
    <alpha 
        android:fromAlpha="0.8"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:duration="1000" />

    <!-- Flip image once it's in the center -->
    <!-- ***** HERE IS THE only offset I set ****** -->
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:startOffset="2000"
        android:duration="200" />
</set>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. No what I am looking for is to have the translation and alpha performed at the same time, with the flip animation starting once the image has moved to the center and is fully opaque